# Laravel-6: Deleting Logged in user : The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal, laravel-6

**EDIT! LATEST CODE UPDATED, NEW ERROR^** 
I am currently designing a website which has a feature for users to create an account.
I am encountering problems trying to get the user to be deleted first of all, then for the user to be deleted whilst logged in.

My Users controller looks like so:

```
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        Auth::logout();

        if ($user->delete())
        {
         return Redirect::route('\home')->with('global', 'Your account has been deleted!');
        }
    }
```

My Modal bootstrap window that opens from a form looks like this;

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Are you sure?</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <form action="{{route('users.delete', ['user' => Auth::id()])}}" method="Post">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      @csrf
      @method('delete')
      <div class="modal-body">
        Are you sure you want to permanetly delete your account?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">No, cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Yes, delete my account</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The form the modal opens from:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                <img src="{{ asset('/uploads/avatars/' . $user->avatar ) }}" style="width:100px; height:100px; float:left;
                margin-right:25px ">
                <strong>Delete {{$user->name}}'s account?</strong></div>
                <div class="card-body">
                <form action="delete" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Account Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" name ="email" value="{{$user -> email}}" class="form-control" readonly>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="text-centre">
                    <p></p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">
                        Delete
                    </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally my route looks like this;

```
Route::post('/users/delete', 'Admin\UsersController@destroy')->name("delete-account");
```

Any ideas on how to firstly get this working and secondly implement it are welcome. thank you

Comment: Please tell the error you are getting. It will help in proposing right answer.

Comment: Nothing is happening when i click the "Yes, delete my account" button in my modal window.

Comment: You should not add `method_field('patch')` in form for a route of `get` type. I mean you should define type using `Route::delete`.

Comment: I was under the impression some browsers don't support the delete type

Comment: Quite possible. But have a look on my answer. I have used `POST` method and added `_method` field with value `delete` . `@method('delete')` will be doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Please tell us the error you are getting.

The first thing I recognize seeing your code is, that you return on the second line of your method. But after the return, you are still expecting code to run. Unfortunately, this will not work. Code after a return is ignored.

Try to split the methods:

```
Route::delete('/users/destroy', ['uses' =>'Admin\UsersController@destroy', 'as' => 'users.destroy']);
Route::get('/users/delete', ['uses' =>'Admin\UsersController@delete', 'as' => 'users.delete']);
```

Form method and request should be like this:

```
  <form action="{{route(users.destroy)}}" method="delete">
```

Comment: Thanks. How do i display the view ?

Comment: The error is that nothing happens when I click the confirm to delete button in my modal window

Comment: You should split the route. Make another function for the view (GET) and remain the destroy method for the delete function, and please use DELETE request for that.

Comment: I will Edit question for new code if you want to look. Just being met with looking id of non object now from my delete method

Answer (score 0):

Actual problem was the mismatch of route types. You have defined a route of `GET` type while the form is submitted to a route of `DELETE` type.

Please replace your code with this one and check:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Are you sure?</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <form action="{{route('users.delete', ['user' => Auth::id()])}}" method="Post">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      @csrf
      @method('delete')
      <div class="modal-body">
        Are you sure you want to permanetly delete your account?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">No, cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Yes, delete my account</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And change your route to this

```
Route::delete('/users/{user}', 'Admin\UsersController@destroy')->name("users.delete");
```

Your controller lacks an IF-THEN statement

```
public function destroy(User $user)
    {

        if($user->id !== Auth::id()) return view('admin.users.delete')->with('user', Auth::user());

        Auth::logout();

        if ($user->delete())
        {
         return Redirect::route('\home')->with('global', 'Your account has been deleted!');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Met with error The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE., even thought I have changed refreshed and saved route to Route::delete('/users/{user}', 'Admin\UsersController@destroy')->name("users.delete");

Comment: You have set the value of `method` to `GET` in `form` tag. Please change it to `method="POST"` in your `<form>` tag.

Comment: Please review my updated code. Met with Trying to get property 'id' of non-object error now from my delete method within my usersController

Comment: Output for your changes results in The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE

Comment: You forgot the Route change. `User` model will be provided to your `destory` method if you put route URI like the one I have mentioned. `/users/{user}`.

Comment: Missing required parameters for [Route: users.delete] [URI: users/{user}]

Comment: Sorry! Fixed that `action="route....` line. Please correct it in your code as well.

Comment: Still receiving the Output for your changes results in The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE ,mate this is baffling me

Comment: As you have revealed your problems in comments. I have added a new answer please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with this one and check:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Are you sure?</h5>
        <form action="{{route('delete-account'}}" method="Post">
        @csrf
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        Are you sure you want to permanetly delete your account?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">No, cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Yes, delete my account</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And change your route to this

```
Route::post('/users/delete', 'Admin\UsersController@destroy')->name("delete-account");
```

Your controller lacks an IF-THEN statement

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        Auth::logout();

        if ($user->delete())
        {
         return Redirect::route('\home')->with('global', 'Your account has been deleted!');
        }
    }
```

Comment: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: Seems any other route type than get isn't working for me

Comment: Have you closed the `form` tag. As I forgot to close it. HTML code updated. Please check it.

Comment: Form tag is closed yes

Comment: Please update your code from my answer and check it again.

Comment: Still same error The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. I really don't know what is causing this

Comment: When i run php artisan route:list cmd, beside the user.delete route is  GET|HEAD  | users/delete            | users.delete, would that be what is causing it?

Comment: However beside users.destroy is  DELETE    | admin/users/{user}      | users.destroy

Comment: To remove all confusions. I have changed route name to `delete-account` and updated HTML code accordingly. Please give it a try.

Comment: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
There must be something causing only the get method to work, baffling me I had no problems until this point!